# does acid rain damage the octopus king minion in candy box 2?

Tags: candy-box-2

So I'm farming candy at the Castle's Entrance. I have equipped the Boots of Introspection, the obsidian Octopus crown, and the Monkey Wizard's enchanted staff.

Trouble is, I'm now stuck behind a giant wall of Octopus minions and can't get to the exit. I've been spamming teleport but it hasn't gotten me any closer, and more often than not sends me right back to the start.

If I start spamming acid rain instead, will it do enough damage to the octopi so that I can jump my way clear? Or is my only hope the exit without loot button and lose the ~2 million candies I've accumulated so far?

Comment: You don't happen to have black demons or the pogo stick do you?

Comment: Just teleport and jump continously

Answer (score 2):

Acid Rain doesn't damage Octopus Minions. Only Demons do.

Answer (score 2):

you can teleport and when you fall, spam the jump button.
hope this helps.